# Problems with using ZipOutputStream and ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, stream, zip

Right now, I am using the pure ObjectOutputStream to pass objects over a socket. Sometimes, these objects can become very big and cause OutOfMemory issues. I believe the objects can get compressed though, as there is much repeated data inside of them, usually. So, I attempted to wrap my socket with:

```
  static class CompressedSocket extends Socket {
    private ZipInputStream zis;
    private ZipOutputStream zos;

    CompressedSocket(InetAddress inetAddress, int port) throws IOException {
      super(inetAddress, port);
      zis = new ZipInputStream(super.getInputStream());
      zos = new ZipOutputStream(super.getOutputStream());
    }

    @Override
    public ZipInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
      return zis;
    }

    @Override
    public ZipOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
      return zos;
    }
  }
```

However, in the part of my class where I wrap the sockets in ObjectInput/OutputStreams, I get the following error. Here are the relevant lines:

```
ObjectInputStream in = null;
ObjectOutputStream out = null;
Object serverResponse = null;
CompressedSocket socket = null;
try {
    socket = new CompressedSocket(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress), SixDofServer.PORT);
} catch ( ... ) { ... }

try {
    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
} catch ( ... ) { ... }
```

The error that comes out is:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: no current ZIP entry
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

So, clearly I am not doing something right. But I am finding Google and other guides to be of little help.

Now, if it turns out that wrapping a socket stream is just not an option, for whatever reason, I would still like to compress that object I was referring to in the beginning. Any suggestions on how to compress that object locally, then send it over the regular ObjectOutputStream?

Comment: Don't think it's a socket issue, you may need to supplya zip entry before writing to the socket...

Comment: You most likely want to use a `DeflaterOutputStream` or `GZIPOutputStream` if your objective is to compress a stream of bytes.  The ZIP format is a structured file with a directory and member entries.

Comment: Deflater nor GZIP are working either, though I am getting different issues. Both of those seem to block indefinitely at the instantiation with ObjectIOStream.

Comment: What exception do you get when using GZIP of Deflater? Can't be the same.

Comment: I've done this but with `GZIPOutputStream`. You can't use `ZipOutputStream` as there is no `ZipEntry.` It's non-trivial: for example you need to call `finish()`.

Comment: @EJP (first off, thanks for contributing to many of my other questions) -- do you have examples of how you made GZIPI/OStream work? If so, I'll vote it up if you make it into a seperate answer. As I mentioned earlier, I did not have luck with using GZIP I/O.